# Share Pictures to other apps

Tags: android, image, share, send, android-image

I've been busting my head on this. I had it. The app was sending the picture to any other app. I tried with WhatsApp, Gmail, etc. But, now it's not working. What can it be? Packaging problem? Keystore problem? Now, when I try to use Gmail, the attachment shows up, but it looks like an empty picture with its name. That means that is not finding the file on the Smartphone. Thanks guys.

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

private void dragonFile(){
    Bitmap dragonFront = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.phoenix_art);
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "phoenix_art.jpeg");
    try{  
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        dragonFront.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    dragonFile();
    File downloadedPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "phoenix_art.jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
    return shareIntent;
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the file explorer on DDMS to verify the file was actually created?  You should be able to see the file and then pull it off (from either emulator or device) and onto your development computer.  The fact that gmail gets a file that is only a name but looks empty means that getDefaultShareIntent() sees a file and correctly attaches it to the intent. That means it's likely in dragonfile() where the problem resides, although I don't see what it is.

Comment: It seems that is not creating it. But, that is the strange thing. It was doing it. :/

Comment: but is it actually doing anything than creating a file?  The file is obviously there, or you'd get an error putting it in as an extra. IS the file really an image?